# Prettier not formatting Unity C# Code - "Cannot format Movement.cs"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, prettier

when I create a simple .cs file in VS Code in any folder, without a project setup or anything, it will format correctly using the Prettier extension (onSave).

But I cannot get the autoformatting to work when I open a C# file from unity. Or in a Unity Project.

In the left bottom bar I get an error:
"Extension Prettier - Code Formatter cannot format Assets\Movement.cs"
[image]
I've checked the developer console and there is no error or anything.

Answer (score 13):

That's because Prettier can't format C#.

To format C# code:

1. Install [C# VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) by Microsoft
2. Add these to your VS Code `settings.json`

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[csharp]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
}
```

3. Create a `omnisharp.json` file at your unity project directory and set the formatting options (see [options](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/wiki/Configuration-Options))

```
{
  "FormattingOptions": {
    "organizeImports": false,
    "UseTabs": false,
    "TabSize": 4,
    "IndentationSize": 4
  }
}
```